# Microsoft Edge F12 Developer Tools don't open

Tags: windows-10, developer-tools, ie-developer-tools, microsoft-edge

After upgrade to Windows 10, I can't get the F12 Developer Tools to show / work under MS Edge.

IE 11 developer tools do still work, but I can see rendering differences on my websites I am working on between them, so could do with getting them working under Edge.

I am presuming they are available??

Have already tried the re-register packages fix, as well as reset Internet Options, but nothing works.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I work on the Microsoft Edge team, and have not personally heard of any issues regarding the developer tools not working. As pointed out in [another answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32511495/54680), the tools will only be available via menu and F12 when you navigate to a document. The tools don't work for things like the New Tab Page.

If you continue to experience issues with the Developer Tools, please share additional information about your build of Windows 10 (run `winver` from Run), and Microsoft Edge (version number available in Settings). I'll gladly file an issue for further investigation.

In the meantime, you could try another utility on Windows 10 called the F12 Chooser. You'll find this under `C:\Windows\System32\F12\F12Chooser.exe`. This will identify all possible debug targets presently opened on your machine. You should see an instance of Edge enumerated.

Comment: Yeah - I realize it needs to be on a website (rather than an internal) but doesn't work - the mouse cursor quickly flashes to waiting (hourglass) but then back to cursor. WinVer = Windows Version 10.0 (Build 10240). Edge = MS Edge 20.10240.16384.0. All Windows Updates installed (think last cumulative was got on Tuesday).

Comment: Tried F12 chooser and the enumeration contains two targets - one is "Stack Overflow", the other lists 00000070.

Comment: UPDATE - After running F12 Chooser and selecting the "Stack Overflow" option, the dev tools opened. Rebooted and now F12 works on websites in Edge!! Thanks!!!

Comment: When I press `F12` I get a blue window with the IE logo on it .... and that's all. Nothing more ever appears in this window.

Comment: F12 tools are not loading on Edge (build 17063), they remain blank.

Comment: Can you help with this related bug? https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/15458103/ What can I do?

Comment: Moreover `F12Chooser.exe` is not present on build 17063. I have tried to launch `IEChooser.exe` but it doesn't list any target (even when Edge is opened on a web page).

Comment: I just ran into this issue on Win10 V1803 (Build 17134.1) / Edge V42.17134.1.0. Running C:\Windows\SysWOW64\F12\IEChooser.exe and selecting the target tab (when Edge was open on a web page) caused the F12 Developer Tools to appear.

Comment: IEChooser has a line saying "Choose target to debug", but there's nothing below it. Nothing to choose. WinPro 10.0.18362

Answer (score 12):

The following issue page contains a solution for this in the comments, which worked for me:
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/18153935/

> If you are allowed to use powershell, execute the following command as your user to fix the dev tool: `Add-AppxPackage -register "C:\windows\SystemApps\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdgeDevToolsClient_8wekyb3d8bbwe\AppxManifest.xml" -DisableDevelopmentMode -Confirm:$false`

Answer (score 3):

## Answer

If you open Edge without having gone to a website first, then the F12 Developer Tools will not be available. For instance, if you just open a new tab, then you will not have the tools. Once you actually go to a website, the tools will again be enabled.

## Disabled

[image: Disabled in a new tab.]

## Enabled

[image: Enabled at a website]

Answer (score 2):

The "developer tools blank" phenomenon is a known issue, as you can see here: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/15458103/

The solution is yet unknown. I have the same effect here on my computer with one account, but I can see the tools page with a different user account on the same machine. So I think this might be an issue connected to the user profile.

Comment: "Sorry, we couldn't find that page."

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this will help anyone. But I use edge a lot and after one update my F12 didn't work, I searched and found out that the update turned off the F12 on edge settings. Open the Settings find for F12 and mine was disabled.
That simple, and never thought about it.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely **nothing worked** for me, except [this](https://appuals.com/microsoft-acknowledges-issues-with-edge-developer-tools-and-sql-connection-in-cumulative-update-kb4462933/):

> Using Administrator permissions, delete the following files and restart Developer Tools:

The folder is `%windir%\SystemApps\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdgeDevToolsClient_8wekyb3d8bbwe\microsoft.system.package.metadata\Autogen\` and the exact file depends on system arch:

- x64: `JSByteCodeCache_64`
- x86: `JSByteCodeCache_32`

Comment: @Ralf Unfortunately the problem causes seem to be unique.

Comment: After much trying, the tools eventually appeared. But I have no idea what actually fixed it. Trying now, they are gone again. I'm glad it's unique ;-)

Answer (score 0):

1. Open Microsoft Edge.
2. Click on the `three dots` in the upper-right corner of the window.
3. Select `Settings` from the drop-down menu.
4. Scroll down to the `System` section.
5. Toggle the switch next to `Open the Developer Tools` when <kbd>F12</kbd> key is pressed to the `On` position

Answer (score -1):

I have this problem today!

I debugged yesterday, no problem, then ran the latest big microsoft update last night and today I have this problem.

You have to close the tab and reopen it and then everything is ok!

Comment: Turning it off and on again is a standard trouble-shooting technique in information technologies. I'm not sure whether it really helps anyone to provide it as answer for this specific issue, esp. when it doesn't even seem to work in most cases.

Comment: Note that I closed my browser, Edge in this case and reopened it. Normally this solves the problem. But in this particular case, I had to close the particular tab sheet and reopen it. I think this is valuable information.