# F12 C:\Windows\SysWOW64\F12\IEChooser.exe not work - black screen

Tags: internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

for a few days now I've been having an error with IEChooser to view code from Edge in IE mode. the problem lies in the fact that, having launched IEChooser and selected the tab of my interest, the tool does not open and the icon remains black. Do you know a way to restore. Grazie

[Select the tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z9tlr.png)
[tool does not open](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oOFvo.png)

I tried this way:
Launch the F12 development tools that corresponds to your version of Office.
For the 32-bit version of Office, use C:\Windows\System32\F12\IEChooser.exe
For the 64-bit version of Office, use C:\Windows\SysWOW64\F12\IEChooser.exe
IEChooser opens with a window named Choose target to debug.
[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/debug-add-ins-using-f12-tools-ie]

I tried another way:
If you are allowed to use powershell, execute the following command as your user to fix the dev tool: Add-AppxPackage -register "C:\windows\SystemApps\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdgeDevToolsClient_8wekyb3d8bbwe\AppxManifest.xml" -DisableDevelopmentMode -Confirm:$false
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32500709/microsoft-edge-f12-developer-tools-dont-open]

Grazie

Answer (score 1):

I don't meet such issue when I use IEChooser to debug web pages in Edge IE mode.

Which version of Edge and OS are you using?

You could try to reset IE-
Windows feature> Turn Windows features on or off> select Internet explorer 11> enable/disable IE.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply.

i tried with this: <<You could try to reset IE- Windows feature> Turn Windows features on or off> select Internet explorer 11> enable/disable IE.>> but i didn't solve it.

I have win11 with Edge 115.0.1901.203 (64 bit)

Comment: Hi, I had tested in the same OS and the same edge version, I don't meet such issue.
Does the problem only occur on one particular site? Or occur on all sites?
Also, you can try to repair IEChooser, open with cmd and type sfc /scannow.

Comment: Thanks for your help Elin Lu.
I tried sfc /scannow but nothing happens.
yes, the problem exists with all sites.

Comment: Based on my research, it seems to be an IEChooser issue. We recommend that you could send a feedback ticket.  1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/devtools-guide-chromium/contact；2. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/send-feedback-to-microsoft-with-the-feedback-hub-app-f59187f8-8739-22d6-ba93-f66612949332

Comment: Thanks man, I will follow your advice. I will inform you later